# How to get current value with datetimepicker plugin

Tags: jquery

Merry christmas to everyone!

I am lost, I read all the documentation and checked on the web for possible solutions but I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I would like to capture the current value of the date selected by the user and put it into an input to later submit it by POST. Problem is that I can not capture the current value of the datetimepicker an as a result of this the data sent by Post through jquery is incomplete.

I leave my code underneath. Hope someone can help me. ( code is very large, I leave only the important bits)

Thank you in advance.

```
    '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                    '<label class="col-lg-2 control-label">From:</label> ' +
                    '<div class="col-lg-10"> ' +
                    '<div class="input-group date" id="from"> ' +
                    '<input type="text" name="fromevent" id="fromevent" class="form-control"/> ' +
                    '<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> ' +
                    '</div> ' +
                    '</div> ' +
                    '</div> ' +
                    '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                    '<label class="col-lg-2 control-label">To:</label> ' +
                    '<div class="col-lg-10"> ' +
                    '<div class="input-group date" id="to"> ' +
                    '<input type="text" name="toevent" id="toevent" class="form-control" /> ' +
                    '<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> ' +
                    '</div> ' +
                    '</div> ' +
                    '</div> ' +

$('#fromevent').datetimepicker({ minDate: new Date()});
    $('#toevent').datetimepicker({minDate: new Date()});

    $("#fromevent").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                $('#fromevent').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
            });
    $("#toevent").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                $('#toevent').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
            });

start = $("#fromevent").val();
                        end =  $("#toevent").val();
                        id_user =  $("#id_user").val();



        if($("#actionchoose").val() == "13"){

           $.post("addactionevent.php", { legalcase_id: id_legalcase, action: action, message: message, start: start, end: end, user_id: id_user}, function(){

                     location.reload();

                }).fail(function() {
                    alert('Unable to send.');
                });
```

Comment: If possible then create `fiddle` for the same. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Parixit, That code is all you need, I don't see necessary to overextend. The idea is just to capture the current date in to an input and send it to another php page through POST jquery.

Comment: You should get date value just before you post it to another page. Try to add `start = $("#fromevent").val();` within `#actionchoose` `if` condition